how to install selenium in conda / ubuntu environment
I have some issues using selenium on ubuntu whereas it works on window 11.
ubuntu : 22.04
gecko driver installed : 0.34
Python of conda environment : 3.10.14
selenium version : by default it is a 3.xxx version installed. I forced with pip to upgrade to 4.19.0 but I have the same issue.
firefox user profile : I copy paste the firefox profil I need in the local folder of my project.
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_profile import FirefoxProfile

profile_path = 'local_folder_profile.default'
profile = FirefoxProfile(profile_path)

options = Options()
options.profile = profile

s = Service('/usr/local/bin/geckodriver')

driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=s, options=options)

after few seconds, a popup is opening then a message appear : Your Firefox profile cannot be loaded. It may be missing or inaccessible.
I'm getting crazy ^^ any tip to fix it ?
